# Adding a new layout to Typo3 NEOS Sites

Tags: neoscms

I followed the steps in this cookbook to create a new layout for my NEOS site:
http://docs.typo3.org/neos/TYPO3NeosDocumentation/IntegratorsCookbook/SelectingPageTemplate.html

But the new layout doesn't popup in the Layout Selector of a page in the backend. The Layout Selector is empty.

Is there something missing in this cookbook. What else do I have to do?

Comment: How does your NodeTypes.xml look like?

Answer (score 0):

I would add a comment instead but I lack the points to do so... could it be that you have the wrong environment path set?

You should have `SetEnv FLOW_CONTEXT Development` either in apache's `httpd-vhosts.conf` or in your `.htaccess`